# multiple credentials not working for dacastro4/laravel-gmail

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, gmail-api

i am using [dacastro4/laravel-gmail](https://github.com/dacastro4/laravel-gmail) for multiple credentials

I have set up the env variables and config file as per the documentation.

for single credentials, it's working fine. when I am trying to use multiple credentials the login is not working. but credentials is storing into folder path

> below is my code sample

```
public function callback()
    {
        $userId = 'user'. rand(1, 100);
        LaravelGmail::setUserId($userId)->makeToken();
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
```

is anyone using that package with multiple credentials? or any solution or alternate is fine.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in Laravel but from what I can understand from the doc, the variables `allow\_multiple\_credentials` and `GOOGLE\_ALLOW\_MULTIPLE\_CREDENTIALS` in the config file and .env respectively simply allows the app to store multiple `credentials.json` files. This implies that you need to have an access to the users' data in order to generate the credentials. Your code sample just generates a random user from `user.1` to `user.100`. Do try to have your app store credentials for users *you* have an access to. It would also be helpful if you can share the exact error you're getting.

Comment: @DuuEyn no errors are coming
It simply redirects to / page but the user is not logged in. But when I try with `GOOGLE_ALLOW_MULTIPLE_CREDENTIALS=false` that time it's working as expected. its showing user logged in and other features like send email is working